# Homeomorphic embeddings of $\mathbb R^n$ in itself

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $h: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a homeomorphism with the image. Does it follow that the image of $h$ has an interior point?

Comment: This is the Invariance of Domain theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain